# What is best way to prevent python requests module blocking indefinitely after computer come back from suspend mode?

Tags: python, blocking, python-requests, suspend

Try to do this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(some_url)
```

In some_url variable, assign some url to download a file, for example. While downloading, force your computer to suspend. Finally, try to come back from suspend mode and you will see that python requests block indefinitely. How can i 'fix' this?

Comment: I know that I could put the requests tasks in some thread or process and, actually, I already do it. But the main program needs to be in a join, waiting for the thread that never exits because its blocked indefinitely by python requests module.